# Creating Copy of Object with Image Object inside

Tags: javascript, image

I'm currently working on a javascript based game engine and I'm having an issue when cloning gameObjects. My gameObject class contains a Sprite field, and my Sprite class contains an Image class field. I set up a copy function, and everything gets copied correctly except the Image field. Here are the three functions being used:

```
function Sprite(x, y, width, height, src, tag)
{
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.width = width;
    this.image.height = height;
    this.image.src = src;
    this.tag = tag;
}

//GameObject Class
function GameObject(sprite, hidden, tag)
{
    this.sprite = sprite;
    this.hidden = hidden;
    if (tag == null) {
        this.tag == "default";
    }
}

function cloneObject(gameObject)
{
    var clone = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(gameObject));

    var i, descriptor, keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(gameObject);

    for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(gameObject, keys[i]);
        if (descriptor.value && typeof descriptor.value === 'object') {
            descriptor.value = cloneObject(descriptor.value);
        }

        Object.defineProperty(clone, keys[i], descriptor);
    }

    return clone;
}
```

In the original gameObject, going up the hierarchy shows that the image field holds a value (or type) img.

image: img

That opens up to the image properties which are all correct (e.g. height: 30).

In the copy gameObject, the image field holds a value (or type) HTMLImageElement {}.

image: HTMLImageElement {}

That opens up to the image properties, in which none are correct (e.g. height: Exception: TypeError: Illegal Invocation ...).

What am I doing wrong?